# LESS: concatenate multiple background rules

Tags: less, background-image, mixins, less-mixins

I have a mixin that creates a gradient with vendors' prefixes, and I would like to add this background to a DIV in addition to another `background-image`.

```
.horizontal(@start-color: #555; @end-color: #333; @start-percent: 0%; @end-percent: 100%) {
    background:@start-color;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, @start-color @start-percent, @end-color @end-percent);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, @start-color @start-percent, @end-color @end-percent);
    background-image+: linear-gradient(to right, @start-color @start-percent, @end-color @end-percent);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
  }

.foo
{
  background-image+:url('bg.png');
  .horizontal;
}
```

I thought the solution could be use of [comma merging](http://lesscss.org/features/#merge-feature-comma), that in my example I added only to standard CSS3 gradient declaration. Doing this, here the generated CSS:

```
.foo {
  background-image: url('bg.png'), linear-gradient(to right, #555555 0%, #333333 100%);
  background: #555555;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #555555 0%, #333333 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #555555 0%, #333333 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

It's correct,  but how to have this also for others vendors prefixes without losing flexibility of mixin? I tried to add `+` sign also on others "`background-image: -webkit....`" rules, but in this case, resulting CSS would be:

```
.foo {
  background-image: url('bg.png'), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #555555 0%, #333333 100%), -o-linear-gradient(left, #555555 0%, #333333 100%), linear-gradient(to right, #555555 0%, #333333 100%);
  background: #555555;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

...obviously not correct... any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Less for generating vendor prefixes (or related items) is not the best way to do it. It is much better to use the libraries like Prefix Free or Auto Prefixer etc.

Having said that, for your case I think using a separate parameter for the image would be the best option. The [`isurl()`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#type-functions-isurl) function returns `true` only if the input parameter is a URL.

The default value for the `@image` parameter is set to `none` because this is not a URL and will take care of the blank/null value handling.

```css
.horizontal(@start-color: #555; @end-color: #333; @start-percent: 0%; @end-percent: 100%; @image: none) {
    background:@start-color;
    & when (isurl(@image)){
        background-image: @image, -webkit-linear-gradient(left, @start-color @start-percent, @end-color @end-percent);
        background-image: @image, -o-linear-gradient(left, @start-color @start-percent, @end-color @end-percent);
        background-image: @image, linear-gradient(to right, @start-color @start-percent, @end-color @end-percent);
    }
    & when not (isurl(@image)){
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, @start-color @start-percent, @end-color @end-percent);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, @start-color @start-percent, @end-color @end-percent);
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, @start-color @start-percent, @end-color @end-percent);        
    }
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
  }

.foo{
  .horizontal(@image: url('bg.png'));
}
.foo2{
  .horizontal(@image: 'bg.png');
}
```

In the above mixin, based on whether the value for the `@image` variable is a URL or not, the appropriate output would be generated.

---

In some cases, you may want to use a color (instead of/in addition to an image) in addition to the gradients and for that you can further enhance the mixin like below:

```css
.horizontal(@start-color: #555; @end-color: #333; @start-percent: 0%; @end-percent: 100%; @image: none; @color: none) {
    background:@start-color;
    & when (isurl(@image)) and not (iscolor(@color)){
        background-image: @image, -webkit-linear-gradient(left, @start-color @start-percent, @end-color @end-percent);
        background-image: @image, -o-linear-gradient(left, @start-color @start-percent, @end-color @end-percent);
        background-image: @image, linear-gradient(to right, @start-color @start-percent, @end-color @end-percent);
    }
    & when (iscolor(@color)) and not (isurl(@image)){
        background-image: @color, -webkit-linear-gradient(left, @start-color @start-percent, @end-color @end-percent);
        background-image: @color, -o-linear-gradient(left, @start-color @start-percent, @end-color @end-percent);
        background-image: @color, linear-gradient(to right, @start-color @start-percent, @end-color @end-percent);
    }
    & when (isurl(@image)) and (iscolor(@color)){
        background-image: @color, @image, -webkit-linear-gradient(left, @start-color @start-percent, @end-color @end-percent);
        background-image: @color, @image, -o-linear-gradient(left, @start-color @start-percent, @end-color @end-percent);
        background-image: @color, @image, linear-gradient(to right, @start-color @start-percent, @end-color @end-percent);        
    }
    & when not (isurl(@image)) and not (iscolor(@color)){
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, @start-color @start-percent, @end-color @end-percent);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, @start-color @start-percent, @end-color @end-percent);
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, @start-color @start-percent, @end-color @end-percent);        
    }
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
  }

.foo{
  .horizontal(@image: url('bg1.png'));
}
.foo2{
  .horizontal(@image: 'bg.png');
}
.foo3{
  .horizontal(@color: blue);
}
.foo3{
  .horizontal(@color: red; @image: url('abc.gif'));
}
```

**Note:** I have used `background-image` property in the above sample but if we want use a solid color along with gradients and/or image, then the `background` property should be used instead.

Comment: Thanks Harry, I took this kind of plugin from a famous CSS framework, that evidently still continues to use hardcoded vendor-prefixes. Anyway, I use it because currently I don't compile LESS with node.js but with a GUI like WinLESS. Is there any way to use libraries without node.js ? Thanks

Comment: Welcome mate. I have never really tried using libraries with Less because I have never done professional web designing so far. I think there must be someway to do it though.

Comment: Wow, very complete answer, it remains also possibility to have **both** color, image and gradient together........... :-))))

Comment: @LucaDetomi: I have modified the code to support all three together also. Please mark the answer as accepted when possible :)