# Concatenate mixins call with "comma merging"

Tags: less, mixins, less-mixins

I'm investigating flexibility of [comma merging](http://lesscss.org/features/#merge-feature-comma) in LESS, and here is a use case that currently seems to not have a solution. `.foo` class has 2 inner-shadows concatenated with `+` sign, provided by language.

I tried to create a mixin that could recreate inner shadow (here without vendor prefixes for brevity). I hoped that `+` sign could be applied also to mixins call, but this generate an error. Like in [another question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912745/less-concatenate-multiple-background-rules#29913000) for a similar topic, it seems that this kind of operation must be fronted manually and not using power of automation given by concatenation function.

Please provide any suggestion to continue using mixin call for this purpose.

```css
.foo
{
  box-shadow+: inset  12px  12px 15px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  box-shadow+: inset -12px -12px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.inner-shadow (@x: 0, @y: 1px, @blur: 2px, @spread: 0, @rgba-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) ) 
{
  box-shadow:inset @x @y @blur @spread @rgba-color;
}

.foo2
{
  .inner-shadow+ (@x: 12px, @y: 12px, @blur: 15px, @spread: 0, @rgba-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8) );
  .inner-shadow+ (@x: -12px, @y: -12px, @blur: 15px, @spread: 0, @rgba-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) ); 
}
```

Comment: @Harry: yes, Harry, please :-) I wrote this here for two reason: first of all a possibile optimized solution, but in addition to share a need with community. Maybe if many users have the same needs, development team could consider extension of method.

Comment: Do you know? I'm thinking the same..... but I didn't tried to look into this yet. Loops in LESS are so confusing.... :-D

Comment: Damn...... this should be a very big limit......... is for this kind of reason that I would push to extension of "comma merging" function. It's could be very very powerful, in readiness of code, but its actual incarnation is very basic.... :-(

Comment: I am sorry mate, I took you totally down the wrong path :( There is a very simple answer and I will post it in answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to put the `+:` for the property within the mixin like shown below.

This would mean that if the same mixin is called more than once within the same scope, the resulting value from each mixin call would be concatenated into one single one. This would not have any harmful effect when there is only one call of the mixin within a particular selector also.

```css
.foo{
  box-shadow+: inset  12px  12px 15px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  box-shadow+: inset -12px -12px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.inner-shadow (@x: 0, @y: 1px, @blur: 2px, @spread: 0, @rgba-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) ){

  -webkit-box-shadow+:inset @x @y @blur @spread @rgba-color; 
  box-shadow+:inset @x @y @blur @spread @rgba-color;
}

.foo2{
  .inner-shadow(@x: 12px, @y: 12px, @blur: 15px, @spread: 0, @rgba-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8) );
  .inner-shadow(@x: -12px, @y: -12px, @blur: 15px, @spread: 0, @rgba-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) ); 
}
.foo3{
  .inner-shadow(@x: 12px, @y: 12px, @blur: 15px, @spread: 0, @rgba-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8) );
}
```

---

**Note:** The concatenation happens whenever the same property is specified more than once within the same selector scope and so the below selector rule

```css
.foo2{
  .inner-shadow(@x: 12px, @y: 12px, @blur: 15px, @spread: 0, @rgba-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8) );
  .inner-shadow(@x: -12px, @y: -12px, @blur: 15px, @spread: 0, @rgba-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) ); 
  box-shadow+: 1px 1px 1px solid red;
}
```

would result in all three shadows getting concatenated together like below:

```css
.foo2 {
  box-shadow: inset 12px 12px 15px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), inset -12px -12px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 1px 1px 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: thanks this could be a perfect solution for this simplified case, but as I wrote in question, I dropped vendor prefixes only for brevity but in real case, they are in. So, for the same reasons explained in [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912745/less-concatenate-multiple-background-rules#29913000) adding `+` in property inside mixin.... is not enough unfortunately :-(

Comment: Prefixes for box-shadow is almost not required anymore (unless supporting very old browser versions) but even in that case, this example should work for something like `-webkit-box-shadow` etc. As long as the property name is the same, concatenation would work.

Comment: Ohhh yes, you're right!!! :-) I did not face that, differently from other case, here property declaration is different!!!! thanks

Comment: Always glad to help mate. I am going to clear out the comments to the question (to reduce noise) and also make some minor edits to improve the question. Please feel free to roll back if you feel otherwise :)